# Citations become question marks until I restart Latex

Tags: citing

I've set up my bib as follows

```
% The following statement selects the style to use for references.  It controls the sort order of the entries in the bibliography and also the formatting for the in-text labels.
\bibliographystyle{plain}
% This specifies the location of the file containing the bibliographic information.  
% It assumes you're using BibTeX (if not, why not?).
\cleardoublepage % This is needed if the book class is used, to place the anchor in the correct page,
% because the bibliography will start on its own page.
% Use \clearpage instead if the document class uses the "oneside" argument
\phantomsection  % With hyperref package, enables hyperlinking from the table of contents to bibliography             
% The following statement causes the title "References" to be used for the bibliography section:
\renewcommand*{\bibname}{References}

% Add the References to the Table of Contents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textbf{References}}

\bibliography{Bibs/vaccination_references,Bibs/ml_references}


% Tip 5: You can create multiple .bib files to organize your references. 
% Just list them all in the \bibliogaphy command, separated by commas (no spaces).

% The following statement causes the specified references to be added to the bibliography% even if they were not 
% cited in the text. The asterisk is a wildcard that causes all entries in the bibliographic database to be included (optional).
\nocite{*}
```

Ive split my bib up into multiple bibs so that it is easier to keep track of changes.  When I use `\cite{}` on a citation in the second bib, it always appears as a question mark until I close and reopen Texstudio.

Any idea why this could be the case?

Comment: Closing and reopen TeXStudio? It should be correct after doing a 2nd compilation!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yeah, I thought so too, but no :(  Still question marks after a second compilation.

Comment: This can happen, when you've got an error which required abortion. I had some cases, where this left a running instance of pdflatex open. Compiling worked without any faults fine afterwards, except for such side effects. Do you have any loops or recursion in your document. This can also happen if you try to redefine `\\\`.

Comment: You haven't mentioned that you actually run BibTeX: Please advise. Which document class do you use? Please also tell us if there are any error or warning messages in the blg ("bibtex log") file.

Comment: Please also confirm that the files `vaccination_references.bib` and especially `ml_references.bib` exist in the subdirectory  "Bibs".

Comment: @MaestroGlanz No recursion. @Mico Those are in that directory, and I am using the book class. In the log I see `!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`.

Comment: This looks like that there is the file open anywhere else.

Comment: Yes, I had the pdf open while I was compiling.  I guess that is the source of the problem @MaestroGlanz

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz Looks like it.

Answer (score 1):

I can just talk about Texmaker and Adobe Acrobat Reader. If Adobe Acrobat Reader opens a file, it locks it unlike i.e. basic Notepad. That means, that if you run pdflatex or similar, there will be an error.
But: Texmaker has this special feature, that it can happen, that the function "Quick Build" breaks. If you run "Quick Build" then, you have to click "View PDF" to see it. This breaking of Texmaker can also happen, in some cases where loops generate errors, infinite loops, infinite output (because of infinite loops).

Since I use a lot of loops, this happens quite frequently to me.